# Show only excluded files in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way (plugins / extensions are perfectly fine) to show ONLY items that are excluded from a project / solution?

I have a project in which I've just done some significant refactoring and several files and folders are no longer needed.  Now I want to remove them from source control (Mercurial, VisualHG plugin is installed in VS2010).  It's a rather large solution so I'd rather not have to manually drill through Solution Explorer to find them.

Or, if someone has another process to do this I'm certainly open to that as well.

Comment: +1: I guess that you and I are the only people with this problem :/

Comment: @Edgar :)  Yeah, I'm still procrastinating on actually doing it...  I'm probably going to throw together a VS add-in to do it.

Comment: @Matthew No, I haven't.  It's not been very high on my priority list, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no existing addon at the moment. As the project files are XML (see below), in theory you could write an app to parse it and then compare it to the contents of the project directory; and enumerate each one gathering a list of items that are not included.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="rootFile.html" />
    <Content Include="Directory1\File1.xml" />
    <Content Include="Directory2\File2.xml" />
<ItemGroup>
```

As for integrating this behaviour into Visual Studio, either file a [feature request with Microsoft](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/) or write this addon.